# History field in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.0

Trying to create a field in a table that will get the old value of another field. My table is very similar to this:

```
 ------------ -------------------- ------------------------ 
| id int(10) | price decimal(5,2) | price_old decimal(5,2) | 
 ----------------------------------------------------------
```

What I am trying to get is the value of `price` field to get copied in `price_old` field `ON UPDATE` of the current record.

> **Is it possible to achieve this only with mysql?**

PS: The data contained in that cell is not critical. The usage is to store the previous price of a item and after to be able to show how it changed. I will only need the last value, not the full history of the table entry. *(My MySQL server is 5.0, if this matters)*

Comment: Sorry I will edit. I meant the `price` field in the `price_old` field

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger ([documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)).

I think this syntax is right but haven't used MySQL in a while so you may have to toy with it. If it's wrong and you get it working please let me know so I can edit it.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `price_trigger`
BEFORE UPDATE ON `products`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.price != OLD.price
        SET price_old = OLD.price;
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) on update rule. There set value of price to price_old

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_price_old`  
    BEFORE UPDATE ON `table_name` FOR EACH ROW  
    BEGIN 
    UPDATE `table_name` SET price_old = OLD.price where OLD.id = id;
    END
```

Comment: se my comment to @DwB's answer :)

Comment: Check now. Updated with sample. (NB: NOT TESTED)